# Cannot create an object of my class - why?

Tags: java, android, class, object

Android studio version : 3.2

I created an class(my first class ever on android studio)
by clicking new on java folder but in main activity I am not able to create an object of that class
[In this image you can see an error free Animal class but in main activity I am not able to create an object out of it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXXbV.png)

Everything else looks fine to me
On rebuilding the project I am getting and error stating "cannot resolve symbol Animal"

I have already tried 
rebuilding my project,
clean build,
restarting android studio

Comment: Welcome to SO. The answer is already under the current Animal code. So, `Animal animal = Animal();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Make sure that class Animal is public.
2. Make sure that class Animal is in your app's package name. This might be the reason if you have copied and pasted the class from a page on the internet.

Comment: Thank you got my mistake because of your point no 2.Actually I created an class by clicking on java folder instead on package folder inside java folder